# Select in JPA only works with ID param

Tags: select, jpa

I am trying to do a SELECT query to find the cars which model are SERIE 1

I have try with this code and it works, but is necessary put the ID to 1. If I do only  marca1.setNombre_marca("BMW"); without put  marca1.setId(1); it doesnt work.

```
          marca marca1 = new marca();
          marca1.setNombre_marca("BMW");
          //only works if I set the ID to 1
          marca1.setId(1);

          Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT c.model FROM car c WHERE c.marcacoche = :param ");
          query.setParameter("param",marca1);
          List<String> resultados = query.getResultList();
```

Any form of get all the BMW cars in JPA without put the ID??

Thanks in advance!!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just do search for an entity `marca` with the field `Nombre_marca='BMW'` in db before do your query. Creating a new `marca` object here is a bad idea, it must be comming from db.

Comment: First search an entity marca BMW and then execute the second query?

Comment: then I must do 2 select query? One to create the marca entity and other to search the cars with that marca?

Comment: Yes. If you want to search by the name of the make, you would need to do something like "SELECT DISTINCT c.model FROM car c WHERE c.marcacoche.nombreMarca = :param" and bind the param to "BMW". JPA would then make the join for you.